# Pandoc Filter to add footnotes to links

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I just wanted to ask if anyone knows a short filter for Pandoc to automatically add footnotes to any links. I just want to have readable link source in my printed documents.
So to specify, I'd like to go from

```
[link](url)
```

To something like

```
[link](url)[^link: url]
```

So in the printed PDF the URL of the links I am referring to, should be visible at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
pandoc -o myfile.pdf -V links-as-notes=true myfile.md
```

This only works in PDF output, but it's simple and doesn't require a filter.
See the User's Guide/README under "Variables for LaTeX."

Edit:  with this approach, you no longer have a hyperlink in the main text, just a note with the URL.  So it's not exactly what you were asking for, but maybe it's enough.

Edit:  here's how you could do it with a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html), retaining the link (untested, but should be close):

```
import Text.Pandoc.JSON

main = toJSONFilter go
  where go (Link attr lab (src, tit)) = Span ("",[],[]) [Link attr lab (src, tit), Note [Plain [Str src]]]
        go x = x
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it was that easy. I'd like to also have the links still there, but you can't have everything :)

Comment: Your second edit does not seem to work, the first link just repeats over and over again: [imgur](http://i.imgur.com/x2Ynwmj.png)

Comment: I edited and used a different approach - again untested (I'm away from an environment where I can test this).

Comment: Note that in new pandoc the definition of Link element changed, so you need to replace `Link lab (src, tit)` with `Link attr lab (src, tit)`, and it works.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to doing it with Pandoc filters, as in [John MacFarlane answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33910810/46058) would be to **use LaTeX** for that, creating a `*.tex` file and including it for example via `-H` / `--include-in-header` option to `pandoc`.

The LaTeX code could look like this (as of yet untested), based on [Heiko Oberdiek answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121986/5886) to [Auto generate list of `\url` usages within document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121977/auto-generate-list-of-url-usages-within-document) question on TeX & LaTeX StackExchange:

```latex
\let\saved@hyper@linkurl\hyper@linkurl
\renewcommand*{\hyper@linkurl}[2]{%
  \saved@hyper@linkurl{#1}{#2}%
  \footnote{\url{#1}}%
}
```

I think the `url` package is automatically included by Pandoc; if not, you would need to add `\usepackage{url}` at the top of above code.

---

Note that the link in footnote in above solution uses `\url{<link-target>}` instead of bare `<link-target>` as footnote contents.  I think it looks better, and there would certainly be no problems with `_` in the URL (I don't know if Pandoc escapes that for LaTeX or not), and no problems with URL-friendly line break handling for very long URLs.

The John MacFarlane answer can be quite simply modified to do that:

```hs
import Text.Pandoc.JSON

main = toJSONFilter go
  where go (Link alt desc (url, title)) = Span ("",[],[]) [Link alt desc (url, title), Note [Plain [Link alt [Str url] (url, "")]]]
        go x = x
```

Answer (score 2):

The following solution provides exactly what the OP requested (and what I need) with **no filter**. Wherever you have a link in your document, it preserves the link, adds a footnote, and in the footnote there's a full URL.

This solution does require you to modify the LaTeX template, though.

## Step 1 (Optional, if you already have a custom LaTeX template)

If you haven't already copied the default template somewhere, do that now using `pandoc -D latex` and saving that output to a file, perhaps `template.latex`, which I'll use as an example name for the rest of this.

## Step 2

Find the following section your template (which is [present](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/ce8226f1a7d64da56117d2f7f351e06225a84614/default.latex#L155-L158) in the default template):

```
$if(links-as-notes)$
% Make links footnotes instead of hotlinks:
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnote{\url{#1}}}
$endif$
```

and replace it with

```
$if(links-as-notes)$
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
% Alias href to originalHref to avoid an infinite loop
\LetLtxMacro{\originalHref}{\href}
% Make links footnotes in addition to hotlinks:
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{\originalHref{#1}{#2}\footnote{\url{#1}}}
$endif$
```

Then run pandoc like `pandoc -V links-as-notes --template=template.latex document.md -o document.pdf`. You're done!

## Step 3 (Optional)

There are a couple tweaks you can make. If you're tired of writing `-V links-as-notes`, you can either:

- Add `links-as-notes: true` to your document's [YAML metadata](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block), or
- Simply remove the `$if(links-as-notes)$` and corresponding `$endif$` from your template.

## References

- [Similar solution, but for LaTeX, not pandoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115486)
- [How to best rewrite a macro in terms of itself without causing an infinite loop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47372)