# How to get links output in a printer-friendly fashion, e.g. as numbered-citation style incuding a list of links at the end?

Tags: html, printing, latex, pandoc, xelatex

`pandoc` turns input such as

```markdown
See [that site](http://my.link)
```

into

> See [that site](http://my.link)

which means the link information will get lost in printing. I would like to get some printer-friendly version, i.e. the links numbered

> See [[1]](http://my.link)

(code `See [[1]](http://my.link "that site"`)

and at the end (or optionally as a footnote when using [xelatex](/questions/tagged/xelatex) to get a pdf) a summary of all links, i.e.

> [1] that site: http://my.link

(whether the original link title shall be in this list or not is optional).

How can this be achieved? Via a filter or is there already some switch for that?

Comment: Strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33900067/321973 but `links-as-notes` only works for pdf output (and even there, it doesn't seem to work for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use footnotes:

```
Here is a footnote reference[^1]

[^1]: Here is the [footnote](http://my.link)
```

which will also result in footnotes in HTML output. For more flexibility, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900067/pandoc-filter-to-add-footnotes-to-links), e.g. this will only work for LaTeX/PDF output:

```
pandoc -o myfile.pdf -V links-as-notes=true myfile.md
```

Edit: this works only if you have the following in your template (from the default-template):

```
$if(links-as-notes)$
% Make links footnotes instead of hotlinks:
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnote{\url{#1}}}
$endif$
```

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately `links-as-notes` only seems to work for named hyperlinks (or not for XeLaTeX?), but not for `<http://my.link>`-style links. And manual footnotes would be tedious...

Comment: Ok, that explains my problem: I'm using mostly `<...>` links which are converted to `\url{...}` instead. So I'll have to do some additional work to have them automatically enumerated...